# How to count frequency of such list using basic libraries?

Tags: python, list, text, count

List looks like this having ascii character and number value, I want to count occurrence of each of ASCII character for 0, 1 and 2
So for A {0=10, 1=2, 2 =12} likewise

```
[('P', 0),
 ('S', 2),
 ('R', 1),
 ('O', 1),
 ('J', 1),
 ('E', 1),
 ('C', 1),
 ('T', 1),
 ('G', 1),
 ('U', 1),
 ('T', 1),
 ('E', 1),
 ('N', 1)]
```

I have tried

```
char_freq = {c:[0,0,0] for c in string.ascii_uppercase}
```

also

```
for i in range(3):
  for x,i in a:
    print(x,i)
```

I want to count X for i where X is [A-Z]
It should give me result like
Character | 0  |  1 |  2
    A       10    5    4

Comment: Please show expected input/output.

Comment: #### Expected Output:
```
Character : First | Interior |  Last
A         : 51644 |   111686 |  1976
B         : 18866 |     8516 |   541
C         : 19577 |    32130 |   725

```

Comment: I don't think anyone understood what you mean. "I want to count occurrence of each of ASCII character...". So let's say for 'P' what is the output you want? There is only one 'P' character in your example so what the output should be for that, and next what is the output for 'E' because it occurs 2 times in your example

Comment: How many times ('P', 0), ('P', 1), ('P', 2), I want to count occurrence of P at 0,1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

although you don't supply enough example data to actually achieve your desired output.. i think this is what you're looking for:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

l = [('P', 0),
     ('S', 2),
     ('R', 1),
     ('O', 1),
     ('J', 1),
     ('E', 1),
     ('C', 1),
     ('T', 1),
     ('G', 1),
     ('U', 1),
     ('T', 1),
     ('E', 1),
     ('N', 1)]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
counts = df.groupby(0)[1].agg(Counter)
```

returns:

```
C    {1: 1}
E    {1: 2}
G    {1: 1}
J    {1: 1}
N    {1: 1}
O    {1: 1}
P    {0: 1}
R    {1: 1}
S    {2: 1}
T    {1: 2}
U    {1: 1}
```

this will give you each ASCII character, along with each unique number, and how many occurrences of each number

Comment: No pandas only basic libraries

Comment: Oops. Well I'll leave the answer ibcase it helps someone else

Comment: Is there a reason for the restriction? This is undoubtedly the easiest code that will achieve it

Answer (score 1):

```py
from collections import Counter

l = [('A', 1),
 ('A', 1),
 ('A', 2),
 ('A', 2),
 ('B', 1),
 ('B', 2),
 ('B', 3),
 ('B', 4)]

data = {}
for k,v in l:
    data[k] = [v] if k not in data else data[k] + [v]

char_freq = {k: dict(Counter(v)) for k, v in data.items()}
print(char_freq)
```

Outputs:

```
{'A': {1: 2, 2: 2}, 'B': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}}
```

Comment: No pandas only basic libraries

Comment: `collections`, containing `Counter`, is [a basic library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).

Comment: @abhijitdhakane As the person above me mentioned, `collection` _is_ a Python standard library. No `pandas` either.

Comment: Yeah this will work is there any faster way using lambda?

Comment: I mean -- this is already `O(n)`. There are ways to use `lambda` expressions, but it won't necessarily make it any faster.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine you just have to make a small change to the  `char_freq` variable to get the expected result:

```
char_freq = {c: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0} for c in string.ascii_uppercase}
for x, i in a:
    char_freq[x][i] += 1
```

to avoid having all the alphabet in your `char_freq` you could use only the necessary characters:

```
char_freq = {c: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0} for c in {t[0] for t in a}}
for x, i in a:
    char_freq[x][i] += 1
```

**output:**

```
{'O': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'T': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 0},
 'N': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'G': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'U': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'E': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 0},
 'J': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'R': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'C': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'S': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
 'P': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0}}
```